# SharePoint 2013 environment performance is slow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, performance

Our SharePoint 2013 environment performance is slow.

Kindly let me know the steps to fine tune the performance and troubleshoot any possible issues?

Comment: Can you add more details about the setup?

Comment: Are you using the same box for sharepoint, domain controller, SQL server etc ? Can you be more specific on your environment ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint performance mostly depends on Hard disk and memory however SP 2013 is a memory beast, so i think machine doesn't have enough memory to run properly. This may be one of reasons. Can you describe more regarding what's your system specifications?